# fgets() is ignoring the first letter of line from text file. Works when a space is added

Tags: c, linux

I wrote a program to rearrange a text a file. I used `fegts()` to copy the data line by line into a `buffer`.
Everything worked, except it keeps omitting the first char of line 4 from the following text file

```
 O     0.580533    -1.111576     1.827241
 N     0.791283    -0.030547     2.529271
 O     0.938920    -0.043192     3.722388
Eu     0.387757     0.171327    -0.654089
 N    -2.454117     0.553935    -1.831953
 O    -3.555931     0.702353    -2.289337
 O     0.859520     1.403791     1.815420
 O     2.535343     1.144752    -2.164160
 N     2.927953    -0.016122    -2.615146
 O     3.864559    -0.147779    -3.357376
```

I used the fgets() like this,

```
FILE *fs=fopen(argv[1],"r");
FILE *ft=fopen(argv[2],"w");

//few conditions here so that the file is read after the second line

char buf[256], colma[3], colmb[23], colmc[23], colmd[23];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fs) == 0)
   break;
sscanf(buf, "%s %s %s %s", colma, colmb, colmc, colmd);

fprintf(ft, "%12s %10s %10s %15s\n",colmb, colmc, colmd, colma);
```

The expected output is

```
    0.580533  -1.111576   1.827241               O
    0.791283  -0.030547   2.529271               N
    0.938920  -0.043192   3.722388               O
    0.387757   0.171327  -0.654089              Eu
   -2.454117   0.553935  -1.831953               N
   -3.555931   0.702353  -2.289337               O
    0.859520   1.403791   1.815420               O
    2.535343   1.144752  -2.164160               O
    2.927953  -0.016122  -2.615146               N
    3.864559  -0.147779  -3.357376               O
```

The output I get is

```
    0.580533  -1.111576   1.827241               O
    0.791283  -0.030547   2.529271               N
    0.938920  -0.043192   3.722388               O
    0.387757   0.171327  -0.654089               u
   -2.454117   0.553935  -1.831953               N
   -3.555931   0.702353  -2.289337               O
    0.859520   1.403791   1.815420               O
    2.535343   1.144752  -2.164160               O
    2.927953  -0.016122  -2.615146               N
    3.864559  -0.147779  -3.357376               O
```

This issue is rectified by adding an additional space to the fourth line of the my source file. The edited file looks like this

```
 O     0.580533    -1.111576     1.827241
 N     0.791283    -0.030547     2.529271
 O     0.938920    -0.043192     3.722388
 Eu     0.387757     0.171327    -0.654089
 N    -2.454117     0.553935    -1.831953
 O    -3.555931     0.702353    -2.289337
 O     0.859520     1.403791     1.815420
 O     2.535343     1.144752    -2.164160
 N     2.927953    -0.016122    -2.615146
 O     3.864559    -0.147779    -3.357376
```

It also works if I add a space to each line of the file using
`sed -i -e 's/^/     /' <file>`

Can anyone point out why my program isn't reading that first letter?

Edit1:
The looping is done this way,

```c
int ch=0,count=0;
ch=fgetc(fs);
while(ch!=EOF)
    {
        if(ch=='\n')
        {
            count++;
            printf("%d\n",count);
        }
        if (count>1)
        {
            char buf[256], ele[256], xcoord[256], ycoord[256], zcoord[256];
            if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fs) == 0)
                break;
            sscanf(buf, "%s %s %s %s", ele, xcoord, ycoord, zcoord);

            fprintf(ft, "%12s %10s %10s %15s\n",xcoord, ycoord, zcoord, ele);
    }
    ch=fgetc(fs);
```

`ch` is initialized as an `int` because it wasn't compiling when initialized as a `char`

Comment: will edit the question with the loop

Comment: I see that now. So I need to count number of lines without affecting fgets? Is that possible?

Comment: What is the relationship between `buf` and `buffer`?  Always show actual code, and make it complete.  If a reader can see everything, they are more likely to be able to help.  If they want to run your code, they should be able to cut-n-paste it without having to add their own boilerplate (eg, `int main(void)` ...).

Comment: I realize my mistake. Will do it right from now. I appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `fgets` fails to read a line, it will exit the loop.

```
int ch=0,count=0;
char buf[256], ele[256], xcoord[256], ycoord[256], zcoord[256];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fs)) {
    if (4 == sscanf(buf, "%s %s %s %s", ele, xcoord, ycoord, zcoord)) {
        fprintf(ft, "%12s %10s %10s %15s\n",xcoord, ycoord, zcoord, ele);
    }
    ++count;
}
```

Comment: `sscanf(buf, "%255s %255s %255s %255s")`  Always include a width modifier to prevent buffer overflow.  Making the buffers bigger is *not* a viable solution.

Comment: maybe you should `count++` only for valid lines, when `sscanf( )` returns 4

Comment: @arfneto I have incorporated that into the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

regarding the two instances of:

```
ch=fgetc(fs);
```

This is consuming the first character of each line.